Dockering a repo with updated submodules
I have a repo dq-mod in the following setup,
|-main.py
|-common_utils/
|-custom_utils/
|-dockerfile
|-start.sh

The common_utils is a submodule which contains some common util files. The custom_utils folder contains utils that are used only by main.py. Some of the repo contents are packaged as a docker image.
Since common_utils is a submodule I can't package its contents into the docker image.
Requirements:

Package the contents of the common_utils during the docker image build
Whenever the docker image is used, use the latest contents from the common_utils

Dockerfile
# Debian 11 is recommended.
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 debian:11-slim

# Get environment argument from docker build command.
ARG ENV_ARG
# Set environment variable.
ENV ENV=$ENV_ARG

# Suppress interactive prompts
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# (Required) Install utilities required by Spark scripts.
RUN apt update && apt install -y procps tini libjemalloc2 git

# Enable jemalloc2 as default memory allocator
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2

# (Optional) Install and configure Miniconda3.
ENV CONDA_HOME=/opt/miniconda3
ENV PYSPARK_PYTHON=${CONDA_HOME}/bin/python
ENV PATH=${CONDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
COPY build_dependencies/Miniconda3-py39_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh .
RUN bash Miniconda3-py39_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda3 \
  && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda config --system --set always_yes True \
  && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda config --system --set auto_update_conda False \
  && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda config --system --prepend channels conda-forge \
  && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda config --system --set channel_priority strict

# (Optional) Install Conda packages.
#
# The following packages are installed in the default image, it is strongly
# recommended to include all of them.
#
# Use mamba to install packages quickly.
RUN ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda install mamba -n base -c conda-forge \
    && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/mamba install \
      conda \
      cython \
      fastavro \
      fastparquet \
      gcsfs \
      google-cloud-bigquery-storage \
      google-cloud-bigquery[pandas] \
      google-cloud-bigtable \
      google-cloud-container \
      google-cloud-datacatalog \
      google-cloud-dataproc \
      google-cloud-datastore \
      google-cloud-language \
      google-cloud-logging \
      google-cloud-monitoring \
      google-cloud-pubsub \
      google-cloud-redis \
      google-cloud-spanner \
      google-cloud-speech \
      google-cloud-storage \
      google-cloud-texttospeech \
      google-cloud-translate \
      google-cloud-vision \
      koalas \
      matplotlib \
      nltk \
      numba \
      numpy \
      openblas \
      orc \
      pandas \
      pyarrow \
      pysal \
      pytables \
      python \
      regex \
      requests \
      rtree \
      scikit-image \
      scikit-learn \
      scipy \
      seaborn \
      sqlalchemy \
      sympy \
      virtualenv \
      # (Optional) Install additional packages.
      openpyxl

RUN ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/mamba install -n base -c conda-forge great-expectations=0.17.22

# (Optional) Add extra Python modules.
ENV PYTHONPATH=/opt/python/packages
RUN mkdir -p "${PYTHONPATH}"
COPY custom_utils "${PYTHONPATH}/utils"

# Copy the start.sh script from the root directory of the project to /etc
COPY start.sh /etc/start.sh

# Make the start.sh script executable
RUN chmod +x /etc/start.sh

# (Required) Create the 'spark' group/user.
# The GID and UID must be 1099. Home directory is required.
RUN groupadd -g 1099 spark
RUN useradd -u 1099 -g 1099 -d /home/spark -m spark
USER spark

# Set the entrypoint to the start.sh script
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/start.sh"]

start.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Clone the submodule repository and copy its contents to the utils directory
git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/python/packages/utils
cd /opt/python/packages/utils
git clone --recurse-submodules -j8 https://github.com/org/common-utils.git common_utils
git submodule update --init --recursive
cp -r common_utils/* .
ls -R .

# Remove the cloned repository
rm -rf common_utils

# Execute any additional commands or the main application
exec "$@"

I try the above scripts but the common_utils contents are never copied to the utils folder.

Can you COPY the directory into your image in the Dockerfile?  Git submodules aren't particularly special at the filesystem level, if you ls -l you should see common_utils as an ordinary directory.

@DavidMaze do you mean to use ls -l instead of ls -R .?

To include the common_utils submodule in the Docker image and ensure that it always uses the latest content when used, you can make changes to the Dockerfile and start.sh script to properly handle cloning and updating the submodule.
Below is an updated version of the Dockerfile and start.sh script to resolve the issues:
# Debian 11 is recommended.
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 debian:11-slim

# Get environment argument from docker build command.
ARG ENV_ARG
# Set environment variable.
ENV ENV=$ENV_ARG

# Suppress interactive prompts
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# (Required) Install utilities required by Spark scripts.
RUN apt update && apt install -y procps tini libjemalloc2 git

# Enable jemalloc2 as default memory allocator
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2

# (Optional) Install and configure Miniconda3.
ENV CONDA_HOME=/opt/miniconda3
ENV PYSPARK_PYTHON=${CONDA_HOME}/bin/python
ENV PATH=${CONDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
COPY build_dependencies/Miniconda3-py39_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh .
RUN bash Miniconda3-py39_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda3 \
  && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda config --system --set always_yes True \
  && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda config --system --set auto_update_conda False \
  && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda config --system --prepend channels conda-forge \
  && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda config --system --set channel_priority strict

# (Optional) Install Conda packages.
#
# The following packages are installed in the default image, it is strongly
# recommended to include all of them.
#
# Use mamba to install packages quickly.
RUN ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/conda install mamba -n base -c conda-forge \
    && ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/mamba install \
      conda \
      cython \
      fastavro \
      fastparquet \
      gcsfs \
      google-cloud-bigquery-storage \
      google-cloud-bigquery[pandas] \
      google-cloud-bigtable \
      google-cloud-container \
      google-cloud-datacatalog \
      google-cloud-dataproc \
      google-cloud-datastore \
      google-cloud-language \
      google-cloud-logging \
      google-cloud-monitoring \
      google-cloud-pubsub \
      google-cloud-redis \
      google-cloud-spanner \
      google-cloud-speech \
      google-cloud-storage \
      google-cloud-texttospeech \
      google-cloud-translate \
      google-cloud-vision \
      koalas \
      matplotlib \
      nltk \
      numba \
      numpy \
      openblas \
      orc \
      pandas \
      pyarrow \
      pysal \
      pytables \
      python \
      regex \
      requests \
      rtree \
      scikit-image \
      scikit-learn \
      scipy \
      seaborn \
      sqlalchemy \
      sympy \
      virtualenv \
      # (Optional) Install additional packages.
      openpyxl

RUN ${CONDA_HOME}/bin/mamba install -n base -c conda-forge great-expectations=0.17.22

# (Optional) Add extra Python modules.
ENV PYTHONPATH=/opt/python/packages
RUN mkdir -p "${PYTHONPATH}/utils"

# Copy custom_utils directory
COPY custom_utils "${PYTHONPATH}/utils"

# Copy the start.sh script from the root directory of the project to /etc
COPY start.sh /etc/start.sh

# Make the start.sh script executable
RUN chmod +x /etc/start.sh

# (Required) Create the 'spark' group/user.
# The GID and UID must be 1099. Home directory is required.
RUN groupadd -g 1099 spark
RUN useradd -u 1099 -g 1099 -d /home/spark -m spark
USER spark

# Set the entrypoint to the start.sh script
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/start.sh"]


Updated start.sh File:
#!/bin/bash

# Clone the submodule repository and copy its contents to the utils directory
cd /opt/python/packages/utils
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/org/common-utils.git common_utils
cp -r common_utils/* .
ls -R .

# Remove the cloned repository
rm -rf common_utils

# Execute any additional commands or the main application
exec "$@"


Dockerfile:

The Dockerfile installs the necessary packages and sets up the environment
The custom_utils directory is copied into the image
The start.sh script is copied and made executable
The Dockerfile creates the necessary user and sets the entrypoint to start.sh

start.sh:

The script clones the common_utils repository with submodules
It copies the contents of common_utils into the /opt/python/packages/utils directory
It lists the contents of the directory to verify the copy
It removes the cloned common_utils repository to clean up
It executes any additional commands or the main application provided to the container


This setup ensures that every time the Docker container is started, it
pulls the latest common_utils submodule and includes it in the utils
directory, fulfilling the requirement to always use the latest
contents from common_utils.

